# CMake to reload CMakeLists.txt during build

Tags: cmake

### The short version

during a compilation with CMake, a tool can modify (only once) the CMakeLists.txt file. If this happens, I would like to be able to restart the compilation from the beginning (rereading of dependencies, compilation flags, ... Is this possible? (and how to do it :) ?

### The long version

My application deals with an RTOS for embedded systems. I have one file (.oil) that describes the application (tasks properties, sync…) and several C/C++ source files (OS, drivers, app). The system is built in 2 steps:

- a dedicated compiler (goil) generates the data structures of the applications (.c/.h/.s)
- `gcc` compiles all the stuff and `ld` links

The .oil file also embeds some compilation rules (flags, ...) and the compiler (goil) generates a build script in Python. The first time, we call goil directly (bootstrap), and then the python script calls goil if the .oil file has been updated.

I would like to switch to CMake. The problem is:

- I first call goil that generates the CMakeLists.txt (bootstrap). Ok
- then Cmake will call goil again if the .oil is updated and will generate the binary. Ok
- but goil **can also update the compilation rules and generate again the CMakeLists.txt**. In this case, the compilation follows, with the old configuration, and I have to build twice to have the correct behavior. Is it possible to force CMake to restart from the beginning at some point? Here is my cmake rule (that calls goil):

```
#goil
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${APP_GENERATED_SRS}
    DEPENDS ${OILFILE}
    COMMAND ${OILCOMPILER} ${OILFLAGS} ${OILFILE}
    #Here if CMakeLists.txt has been updates, I would like to restart…
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
    COMMENT "call Goil (.oil to code source)"
)
```

regards

Comment: Can you most a minimal, reproducible example? Is this goil tool open source? If you _must_ generate CMake code, then it's probably best to orchestrate this with `ExternalProject`.

Comment: I recommend using Premake (https://premake.github.io/). It is MUCH better!

Comment: @A.Hendry - premake won't help at all if their code generator is producing CMake sources...

Comment: Hi @AlexReinking, goil is open source and is part of Trampoline an open source RTOS that is compilant to AUTOSAR standard (automotive std). It is on [GitHub](https://github.com/TrampolineRTOS/trampoline). 
However, `goil` is not the problem here: from an input source, it will just update the CMakeLists.txt. I would like that cmake restarts if the call to goil has updated the CMakeLists.txt. 
Regards,

Comment: Hi @A.Hendry, 
I am not sur it will help. the tool (goil) will generate the CMakeLists.txt. regards,

Comment: @Mik Convert it from CMake to Premarket. They can waste their time trying to learn the travesty that is CMake, or learn Premake and actually get something done. My point is CMake is trash.